# Traditional DB singleton connection works poorly

Tags: java, jdbc, query-performance

I am using singleton database connection inside my java application, here is code of my connection manager class:

```
public abstract class DatabaseManager {
    //Static instance of connection, only one will ever exist
        private static Connection connection = null;    
        private static String dbName="SNfinal";
        //Returns single instance of connection
        public static Connection getConnection(){       
            //If instance has not been created yet, create it
            if(DatabaseManager.connection == null){
                initConnection();
            }
            return DatabaseManager.connection;
        }   
        //Gets JDBC connection instance
        private static void initConnection(){           
            try{        
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                   String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
                      "databaseName="+dbName+";integratedSecurity=true";

                DatabaseManager.connection =
                             DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);        
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e){       
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(0);
            }
            catch (SQLException e){         
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(0);
            }
            catch (Exception e){        
            }       
        }
    public static ResultSet executeQuery(String SQL, String dbName)
    {
        ResultSet rset = null ;
        try {
               Statement st = DatabaseManager.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
               rset = st.executeQuery(SQL);
               //st.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return rset;
     }

    public static void executeUpdate(String SQL, String dbName)
    {
        try {
               Statement st = DatabaseManager.getConnection().createStatement();
               st.executeUpdate(SQL);
               st.close();
        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
     }
}
```

The problem is my code work perfect at the start but when time past it becomes really slow. What caused that problem and how can i fix that?
At starting time my application handles around 20 queries per second, after 1 hour of running it reaches to 10 queries per second and after 3 days of running it reaches to 1 query per 10 seconds!!
P.S: My application is a single user application that makes many queries through database.
P.S: Here is my JVM parameters in eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms500m
-Xmx4G
-XX:MaxHeapSize=4500m
```

**Unfortunately database is remote and I have not any monitoring access to it for finding out what is going on there.**

Here is the example of my usage:

```
String count="select count(*) as counter from TSN";
ResultSet rscount=DatabaseManager.executeQuery(count, "SNfinal");
if(rscount.next()) {
    numberofNodes=rscount.getInt("counter");
}
```

Comment: use @singleton  in your class

Comment: Even for a single user application, I'd suggest to use a connection pool (eg BoneCP) with a very small pool. Just obtain a connection and close when you are done with it, the pool handles checking the connection, replacing it if it has been open for a long time etc. It also guards your code against uncommitted transactions etc from previous executions.

Comment: Actually I need to run queries as fast as possible. I first did used c3p0 but its performance for my application was really less that traditional singleton connection (around 90% slower!)

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason may cause your issue. So I would suggest you to have a check on the DB side to see if you can find any clue. And are the queries the same?

Comment: I did that already! didnt find anything. Yes all queries are same, reading some data from different tables, running some process on that and write it in other table. there are around 800k iteration for that, I could say that it almost stop at 200th iteration! Could it be related to garbage collector?!

Comment: A program slowing down can be caused by a lot of things, most of the time not the one you expect. Get a profiler (JProfiler, YourKit, ...), a GC analyzer (JClarity Censum), a JDBC logger (https://github.com/soulgalore/jdbcmetrics), a Heap analyzer (Eclipse MAT, JProfiler, YourKit, ...) and get some real insight on where you loose time.

Comment: Yes GC can slow down system, maybe it works fast till first major collection. Start with -XX:+PrintGCDetails and -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps options and you see if frequency of GCs will increase and how much time that consumes. Also good way is to enable JMX and connect console to application to see memory, threads and other info. Good luck.

Comment: Actually it could be memory leak so more and more time is spend by GC when memory consumption grow. Can you please post used JVM options. Thx

Comment: Why is your `st.close()` commented out? Are you correctly closing `ResultSets`? JDBC is not easy to use when it comes to correct resource handling. I suggest you to use wrapper library like *spring-jdbc* and its `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Also your argument that connection pooling is slow seems a bit strange. When it comes to DB communication a few method call overhead is insignificant. But I agree that if your use-case does not require connection pool, there is no need for it. The only advantage you might be missing is connection validation.

Comment: I added the JVM opetions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a disconnected resultset like a CachedRowSet http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html

```
public static ResultSet executeQuery(String SQL, String dbName)
{
    CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    ResultSet rset = null ;
    Statement st = null;
    try {
           st = DatabaseManager.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
           rset = st.executeQuery(SQL);
           crs.populate(rset);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }finally{
        rset.close();
        st.close();
    }
    return crs;
 }
```

CachedRowSet implements ResultSet so it should behave like a ResultSet.

http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/06/23/cachedrowset.html

In addition to these changes, I would recommend you use a pooled datasource to get connections and close them instead of holding on to one open connection.

http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/

Or if you arent java7, bonecp or c3po.

EDIT:

To answer your question, this solves your problem because `CachedRowSetImpl` doesnt stay connected to the database while in use. 
This allows you to close your `Resultset` and `Statement` after you've populated the `CachedRowSetImpl`.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: would you please why this solution solved my problem?! I monitored jvm resource usage in both approaches. It seems that the default method was better from the resource management point of view so it could not be caused by high usage of resources!!

Answer (score 3):

> What caused that problem and how can i fix that?

The main problem that you have here is in the `executeQuery()` method.
You are not closing the `Statement`, I suppose that you have commented the line `st.close()` because you need the `ResultSet` open
for further processing. 
I can see that your idea is to avoid see duplicate JDBC code in your application, but this is not the right approach.

The rule is: close the `ResultSet` and after that, close the `Statement`, 
otherwise you are not releasing resources correctly and you expose to the kind of problem that you are describing.

[Here](http://www.java-blog.com/correct-closing-jdbc-resources) you can find a good explanation about how to close resources correctly (take in mind that in your case you don´t need 
to close the connection)

**Edit:**
An example could be

```java
try{
Statement st = DatabaseManager.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rsCount = st.executeQuery(count);         //count="select count(*) as counter from TSN";
if(rsCount.next()) {
    numberofNodes=rscount.getInt("counter");
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //log exception
} finally {
    rsCount.close();
    st.close();
}
```

Comment: I can not close result set or statement because of multiple queries that I want to run. As soon as I closed them I got error.

Comment: The assigned memory does not full so it could not be memory problem. I think it caused by something else, but I dont know what.

Comment: I insist that your executeQuery() method is not well designed. Try to make some refactoring that allow you to close the statement. 
I don´t know your app code but it should be eassy replace every DatabaseManager.executeQuery() method call, for tree sentences 
(1-> get Connection, 2->create Statement, 3-> get ResultSet) that allow you to close the ResultSet and especially the Statement.

Comment: I added an example of how this method is called, would you please explain your idea on this example?

Comment: Changing that in all part of my code is really time consuming so I chose Summit solution. I was wondering why that solution totally solved my problem!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Although Connection Manager would close `Statement` and `Resultset` automatically, but it would be better if you close them immediately.
2. There's nothing else in your code will effect your single thread task, so I bet there must be something wrong in your database. Try to find out if there's any database locking or wrong column index. And also have a look at database query status, find out where's the bottleneck.

Comment: If it is database problem why it should extend with passing time?

Comment: Because your data set is keeps growing, query 100M records is definitely slower than 100K records.

Comment: No it is not growing, I did the query process record by record!